# react-intl: unicode character

Tags: json, reactjs, react-intl

Is it possible to make unicode characters work within react-intl json dictionaries?
For example in en.json

`My custom &supTM application`

displays "&supTM" instead of <sup>TM</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode character [`\u2122`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol). So it'd be like this in your json file

```json
{
   "MESSAGE": "My custom \u2122 application"
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit React-Intl Unicode Character]